# Sound goes off in headphones randomly

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, headphones, audio-output

Motherboard : Asus P8P67
Audio drivers : Realtek, ATI & AMD high definition audio device, high definition audio device

Sound is off in the headphones & when the audio goes off, the video doesn't plays either. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers like hundreds of times & rechecked detection of hardware changes in Device Manager but no use. 
I also tried installing alternate sound managers for that (Realtek) but it's still happening. Besides sound output, it also takes away the mic recording simultaneously and doesn't shows either devices (Speakers & Mic on my headphones) in Sound, besides showing an AMD HDMI Output which is not plugged in cause I don't use HDMI for audio. It's only when I restart more than a few times, it detects the speakers. 
Also I reinstalled the Win7 OS once but no luck, it happened before and sound is still going off randomly after the reinstallation. 
I can't understand where exactly is the fault and what should I do about it? Would really appreciate the help here.

Comment: Try flashing the BIOS if you feel comfortable doing so. The motherboard/BIOS is what actually detects hardware devices as opposed to Windows itself so the problem could be somewhere in there.

Comment: If the above doesn't solve it then it's time to replace that motherboard.

Comment: Thanks, flashing BIOS somewhat made the performance better and faster, but it still happens, should I try dual booting or over clocking?